# Matlab hit and miss of circle area

Tags: matlab

It works for the most part until the end of the for loop but I get an error not sure how to fix or if its all just wrong.

Problem:

The USF math department has forgotten the value of pi and they want you to calculate it for them. Assume you have a quarter circle inside a square with sides of 1x1 unit. Then the radius of the circle is 1. The area of a circle is pir2. If r = 1, the area is pi and the area of a quarter circle is pi/4. Use a for loop beginning at 1 and ending at a number input from the keyboard to add random points in the square (use the MATLAB function rand() to get the points). If a point lands inside the circle, it is a hit else it is a miss. The approximate area of the circle (pi) is the (hits)/(total points)*4.

My attemp:

```
clear;clc
numP=input('Enter the number of points to test: ');
randNums=[rand(1,numP);rand(1,numP)]'
row=0;
hits=0;
total=0;
for i=1:numP
    while i<=numP
        dist=sqrt((randNums(row+1))^2 + (randNums(row+(numP+1))^2))
        if dist <= 1
            hits=hits+1            
        end
        total=total+1
        row=row+1
    end
end
approx=(hits/total)*4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you should need to do is remove the while loop.

I also got rid of the row variable since you didn't need it.

```
clear;clc
numP=input('Enter the number of points to test: ');
randNums=[rand(1,numP);rand(1,numP)];
hits=0;
total=0;
for i=1:numP

    dist=sqrt((randNums(i))^2 + (randNums(i+numP)^2));
    if dist <= 1
        hits=hits+1;
    end            
    total=total+1;

end
approx=(hits/total)*4
```

Answer (score 0):

```
clear; % Clear workspace.
clc; % Clear command line.
numP=input('Enter the number of points to test: ');
pi_c = 0; % Initialize the computed value of pi.
format long
count = 0; % Count resets to 0 after every value of m.
for j = 1:numP
    x = rand; % Choose a random number 0 and 1.
    y = rand; % Choose a random number 0 and 1.
    if (x^2 + y^2 - 1 <= 0) % If the point falls in a circle...
        count = count + 1; % Increment count.
    end
end
pi_c = 4 * count/numP; % Computed value of pi.
disp(pi_c)
```

pi_c gives you the computed pi value